# Use Spring Feign with Spring Cloud LoadBalancer

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I found this tutorial how to use Spring Cloud LoadBalancer: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/

I'm interested is it possible to use Spring Feign with Spring Cloud LoadBalancer?

Comment: yes, you should add spring cloud loadbalancer as a dependency and it should work like the ribbon integration did

Comment: Thanks, I found this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_cloud/spring_cloud_load_balancer.htm